# Meteor check if index has been created without Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Has somebody found a way to check if an index has been created after calling `_ensureIndex` / `createIndex` **without** using the Mongo Shell but in Meteor server code?

I am writing a package test, where I want to assert, that the indices have been created during some package code execution.

Comment: [rawCollection()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) returns the underying [`Collection`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html) instance from the driver. So there are various methods there for listing or testing for index presence.

Comment: but how? Calling `rawCollection().getIndexes()` returns nothing as is also [not supported on wired Tiger anymore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#compatibility-drivers-wired-tiger).

Comment: Probably because there actually isn't such a method. STOP READING THE SHELL DOCUMENTATION. The NodeJS Driver Documentation is exactly what I gave you a link to. You want [`indexInformation()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#indexInformation) or [`listIndexes()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#listIndexes) or even [`indexes()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#indexes) etc etc. There's a couple more when you actually look.

Comment: Aha, very enlightening. It has never been clear to me, that the node mongo driver actually NOT aims to implement the mongo shell api 1:1, which is why I never checked it's documentation before. (Is this made clear in the Meteor Guide already?) You can create an answer out of this, since a) it works fine in my code and b) it may be important for others as well.

Comment: The `rawCollection()` documentation that I also linked you to also links directly to the NodeJS driver documentation. So yes it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this code to extend collection prototype for getting indexes synchronously:

**`getIndexes.js`**:

```
const Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Mongo.Collection.prototype.getIndexes = function() {
  const raw = this.rawCollection();
  const future = new Future();

  raw.indexes(function(err, res) {
    if(err) {
      future.throw(err);
    }
    future.return(indexes);
  });
  return future.wait();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! If Neil is not posting his comment as answer, I will accept this one. By the way, do you intend to publish this as a meteor package? Could be of use in combination with `createIndex`.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Glad to help. And no, I don't think that such simple piece of code would be of use as package :)